# Play! Render another template inside my template

Tags: java, templates, playframework

I'm using [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.org/) 1.2.3, the CRUD module and Java

Suppose I have this code:

```
@Entity
public class Foo extends Model {
}

@Entity
public class Bar extends Model {
   public Foo foo;
}
```

The class `Foo` has its own template layout (at views/Foo/show.html). The same applies to the class `Bar`:

```
<!-- Bars/show.html -->
#{form action:@save(object._key()), enctype:'multipart/form-data'}
        #{crud.form fields:['foo']}
        #{/crud.form}
...
```

However, I want to edit the 'foo' field inside the html.

I found the #{include} like this:

```
#{include "Foos/show.html"/}
```

but I get an error:

```
 NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'type' on null object.
```

After looking at this [link](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/013cb096417bb478/8c69475538098192?hide_quotes=no&fwc=1) I tried:

```
#{include "Foos/show.html" arg:'object.foo'/}
```

But Play! gives me the error:

```
unexpected token: arg
```

Has anyone had any success attempting to generate html to change the field contents inline ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the link you posted, your code should be

```
#{include arg:"Foos/show.html", foo:'object.foo'/}
```